Why is the Newcomb problem confusing?
[Note: After I made this post, the title and the post have been criticised as badly phrased and/or opinionated. I partially agreed with that and made some initial modifications. However, after others started writing answers, I decided to leave the post as is, so that I would not, as it were, pull the rug out from under those answers. See the chat for details. If you also think that that criticism is warranted, then please interpret the question as "What makes this problem so controversial?" or try to read the post in the light of that question.]
The Newcomb problem is a conceptual puzzle that became widely known after Nozick first presented it (in 1969) and Martin Gardner wrote about it
in his popular Scientific American column (1973). The problem is fascinating, intriguing, and confusing to many people.
Some might see it as a stupid, confusing little mind-twister, but philosophers (who have given it some thought) suggest that it may teach us
something about human decision making. Nozick writes that it confronts us with a paradox of rationality: a conflict between two principles of rational decision making that in the Newcomb scenario seem to lead to different choices. The problem seems to be a neat, small thought experiment, easily repeatable as actual experiment,
and you might guess that after half of century of study and debate, there should be a broad consensus about what to do in this scenario (and why!),
but ... it turns out that there is still just as much controversy as 50 years ago!
According to the Wikipedia entry:

In his 1969 article, Nozick noted that "To almost everyone, it is perfectly clear and obvious what should be done. The difficulty is that these people seem to divide almost evenly on the problem, with large numbers thinking that the opposing half is just being silly." The problem continues to divide philosophers today. In a 2020 survey, a modest plurality of professional philosophers chose to take both boxes (39.0% versus 31.2%).

If you wonder why the percentages don't sum to 100.0%, this is because the rest either thought the problem was unclear or didn't know how to answer or had other reservations. (See: PhilSurvey 2020)
I am very amazed by the controversy. If Nozick's quote is correct then people who take a stand in this debate may be thinking: "How is it possible that about half of the other respondents - academic philosophers - don't see the simple, correct solution? Why is about half of them still confused?" My question then is: "Why is there no broad consensus about what to do (and for what reasons) in the Newcomb scenario?"
Here we have an apparently simple conceptual riddle and yet about half of respondents is not able to see the solution (if there is one). Why?
That is my first, main question: Why is this problem so confusing? (I'm assuming it is also confusing to most non-philosophers, but have only anecdotal evidence. I actually also belief there is a simple, correct solution, but which side I happen to be on in this debate doesn't seem relevant for this question. Or is it?)
It may be impossible to answer that question without directly engaging with the problem and actually proposing a solution? After all, we can only show the fly the way out of the flyglass when we first clearly identify the fly's blind spots and have found a way out for ourselves. But is it perhaps possible to point at some aspects of the presentations that either (potentially) add to the confusion or do the opposite and make it less murky? Are there particular aspects in general (or in this debate) that keep it murky, keep the fly trapped? Have any studies been done of these kind of meta-aspects (of debates or lines of argumentation) that could explain why the debates (in general or in this particular case) are endless? -- This is my second question. I hope it's sufficiently clear.
I actually have more follow-up questions, but I'll leave it at this :)
References

The Wikipedia entry about the problem is fine as far as it goes, but is perhaps not completely unbiased. Also, it mentions several opinions, but the listing appears ad hoc; it's not representative of the rainbow of actual opinions.
Unfortunately the SEP does not have a separate chapter devoted to the problem. It is mentioned in several other entries, though. Practical Reason and the Structure of Actions mentions it in passing. A short (imo extremely flawed) analysis from the standpoint of "causal decision theory" is given in Normative Theories of Rational Choice: Expected Utility. A longer analysis can be found in a link mentioned in a comment below this post.
The Wolpert, Benford presentation(2011) is sometimes quoted as "the" solution, but this is controversial. Their argument is strong, but it stands or falls with their conclusion that the problem is "ill-posed" -- basically that the problem itself allows/requires two different interpretations. But this can be challenged.
A very readable overview of an approach from a computational point of view can be found in a series of blog posts An Introduction to Newcomb-like problems by Nate Soares.


Adam Elga presents a very amusing "take down" of both the causalist and evidentialist views in the form of a dialogue "Newcomb University: A Play in One Act" (2019).
His conclusion leaves the Newcomb Problem (and my question) open:

In my view the moral of the play is not that both causal and evidential decision theories are incorrect. Rather it is that to fully defend either theory’s treatment of Newcomb’s problem it is not enough to just put forward an attractive positive analysis. One should also defend an error theory explaining the source of tempting intuitions that conflict with that analysis.

(See Adam Elga's home page at "www.princeton.edu/~adame")

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

" See the chat for details" What chat?

@KristianBerry - If I understand you correctly, you bring up an infernally touchy point. Adam Elga brings this (your 2nd question) up in https://www.princeton.edu/~adame/papers/newcomb-university/newcomb-university.pdf -- which is a terribly amusing take-down of both the evidentialist and causalist reasonings (but especially the causalist ones). And as far as I know he is the only one who really touched on this (but I've only skimmed a small portion of the literature of course). When you read Elga you will understand why I underlined 'touched' :)

@KristianBerry - The amount of money offered is also psychologically definitely a distracting factor. It's much better to transform the problem using smaller numbers and/or only look at ordinal preference orderings imo. (Psychologically it may be that the Allais paradox comes into play. Arif Ahmed discusses this in "Evidence, Decision and Causality", but I forgot details.)

@mudskipper I agree. I doubt the same choice would be offered if Box A contained a dime rather than $1000. The problem reveals that risk and value/worth have strong psychological/sociological components. Replace the predictor with a blind coin flip and I believe you would see results very similar to that with a predictor:

One thing that I've never seen discussed -- because almost nobody discusses this from the pov of (predictive/descriptive) game-theory but always from the pov of (normative) decision theory -- is the implicit assumption that the predictor is just as good at predicting whether someone (or anyone in particular) will one-box as he is in predicting that they will two-box. This is an assumption we don't necessarily have to make (but which is hidden in the problem story).

This implicit assumption that the predictor would be just as good at predicting the one-box and the two-box choices turns out to actually be a crucial hidden assumption in the CDT argument for two-boxing. So far I have not seen any philosophers who seemed to be aware of this. But it turns out that Maya Bar-Hillel in her analysis (together with Avi Margalit) did identify this as the pain point in the argument.

The confusing part is that we don't know how that predictor works, because that defies our expectation as to how reality works.
Like it's a fact that the truth value of the prediction is determined by the players action to chose either A, B or A+B. (Yes the player could also chose A, just out of spite to show the predictor is wrong, for the price of certainly not getting a chance on the $1,000,000)
It's also a fact that a cause must precede it's effect. Now the action of the player precedes the result, while the prediction precedes the player's action. So if the prediction IS also the result, the prediction would happen both before and after the player's choice. Which is impossible.
OR
The prediction, though unknown, would need to be the determining cause for the player's choice, which would mess with the free choice that the player is offered to, but which might still work given that technically only B is the only viable option if you accept the setup.
So we're either in the realm of fantasy ("pigs can fly? Sure I'll take it"), alternative physics ("Sure I get $1,000,000 but what does that even mean in a universe where cause and effect are weird") or simply a scam ("Thanks for the money, oh did you see the giant over there....").
If we assume we're in fantasy and no matter how ridiculous the rules are, that is just what the the rules are. Then it's, as said, fairly simply: Pick B take your $1,000,000.
You know that by this twisted logic the prediction will show whatever you've actually picked and so when the prediction matches your pick, B is simply the best option, as B nets a million while A or A+B only net $1000.
Same for alternative physics though not sure whether $1,000,000 is even > than $1000 in this upside down reality.
So realistically you'd have to assume it's a scam. Meaning you're having to distinguish between you're the one getting scammed or whether you're a tool to scam someone else. So what does the person offering this game values more their reputation or $1,000,000.
These are variables that are completely outside of our ability of knowing or even guessing them so the only thing you can expect with certainty is that your upfront money to play the game is gone. But jokes aside if we don't consider it to be that scammy you'd be able to expect a safe $1000 picking A and B for the fractional chance of a million. Or gamble on the $0 vs $1,000,000 by picking just B.
Like you could be lucky and they offered this as a bet for $10,000,000 to a 3rd party and supply A with a trapdoor that makes the million drop if A is opened. So picking B would actually yield you a million and lose that 3rd party $10,000,000.
Or they took $100 for you to play the game and once it comes to the reveal they just run and you find a $5 cardboard setting and badly faked $1000 under the transparent glass.
Though the scenario as given would prefer A+B for a conservative run in case of a scam.
Also other answers have pointed out, the psychology of orders of magnitude might mess with us as well. Like due to the 3 orders of magnitude difference between 1000 and 1 million or a 0.1% ratio we default that to basically 0 so the difference to the actual 0 ratio for 0 or $1000 appears to be in the same order of magnitude. So the risk felt in losing the $1000 compared to the reward is seen as low, while in reality you have nothing and after being scammed you'll likely have nothing as well or less, so the $1000 are a hell of a lot more than nothing, while the $1,000,000 is likely just a bait.
So it's essentially the choice between 0 ---  a whole lot --- infinity.
now infinity is a lot bigger than a lot, and a lot is a lot bigger than 0 so depending on which side you're initially drawn to (high reward or loss avoidance) you might prefer the middle as high reward or reject it as basically a loss.

"we don't know how that predictor works, because that defies our expectation as to how reality works." There is a lot of truth in that sentence. People aren't rejecting the logical answer, they are rejecting the premise!

+1 A little long but I think you have it more or less worked out. This makes me think of 'mentalist' tricks. I get how you can use suggestions to get people to do what you want while they think they are in control, but I don't see how that can work all the time. It seems to me that if they chose a person who knows what they are doing, they are in big trouble. I think this also plays into a lot of why people are so impressed with LLM chatbots.

The problem with this argument is that the predictor does not require retrocausation in order to exist. In some presentations, the predictor is "merely" using advanced psychology to determine what the chooser is more likely to choose, which is hardly implausible. In the extreme case, you could just directly ask the chooser which box they would hypothetically choose, while under the influence of some drug that suppresses short-term memory so they don't remember the question or their answer. There is no "fantasy" requirement to do this experiment in real life.

@Kevin - I agree with those points. There is also a very simple way to implement a near perfect predictor: SImply ask the player in advance what they are going to choose. The problem presentation doesn't rule this "implementation" of a predictor out and it obviously doesn't involve any time-travel or retro-causation. This reduces the problem to: How truthful is the player when they say they will choose the one-box? (Basically brings it closer to Parfit's Hitchhiker.) Of course, still not an easy practical problem - for the predictor - but no longer a weird exotic one, at least.

Upvoted for those of us who choose only box A.

@Kevin One way to create a 'perfect' predictor is to cheat: create a device that changes the result as the player is making their choice. That aside, there's a whole aspect of magic/mentalism about 'forcing' people to make a specific choice. I was recently playing a game with my kid where we were making up 'backronyms' for words. One of the words was 'penguin' and we both chose 'igloo' for the 'I' and I think that was maybe more than just coincidence.

"So we're either in the realm of fantasy" Quite a bold claim that determinism is fantasy and not a major open question.

@JimmyJames: If you cheat, it's a different game, and the analysis becomes much simpler and less controversial. Of course you only take the one box if you know that the predictor is cheating - the "you're giving up a free $1000" argument entirely fails to apply to that scenario, because it is not free anymore.

@Kevin I don't really see how cheating makes the situation any different. If the 'predictor is reliable', the results are exactly same as if the predictor is cheating.  I can see how maybe the use of the term 'predictor' might be confusing to people but from a game theoretic analysis, there's literally no difference.

@JimmyJames: I have decided to write my own answer explaining this in greater detail.

Newcomb's paradox is confusing because different answers to it highlight different ways of understanding what it means to make a rational decision.

Evidential decision theory does not distinguish between an event and an action and it assesses a rational decision as one that maximises expected utility. It yields the one-box solution. But evidential decision theory fails to deliver good decisions in lots of cases.

Causal decision theory distinguishes events from actions and assesses a rational decision as one that maximises the expected utility of the causal consequences of an action. An action is treated as an intervention and, when conditionalising on it, one screens off the probabilities of events that are causally independent of the action. This appears to yield the two-box solution, at least on a simple account. Causal decision theory usually gives much more plausible results than evidential decision theory, but it might be argued that the reflexive nature of Newcomb's problem renders it inapplicable.

It might be possible to find a hybrid form of rational decision based both on a consideration of causal consequence and the reflexive nature of the prediction. Some writers have claimed that the puzzle can be understood as having two stages: a pre-prediction stage at which the agent is rationally motivated to decide to take one box, and a post-prediction, post-box-filling stage at which the agent is rationally motivated to take both boxes on the basis that nothing they do now can causally affect the contents of the closed box. This understanding of the problem devolves into another interesting puzzle which asks whether it is rationally possible to make a decision now knowing that one will have no rational reason in future to follow through with it.


Newcomb's paradox has also attracted some analyses based on game theory and these exhibit similar problems. It is often assumed in non-cooperative game theory that if a player has a dominant strategy then it is rational to adopt it. Though arguably this fails in prisoner's dilemma situations. This would yield the two-box solution. But it is also possible to think of the predictor as an antagonist who rewards those who don't follow dominant strategies. Some even claim that the predictor is rewarding irrational decision making. In which case the player is better off going along with the expected pay-off and taking the one box.
So, Newcomb's paradox is capable of telling us interesting things about rational choice and game theory.

From the perspective of policy optimization: adopt the policy that yields maximum reward. This would be a one-box policy.

There seems to be an implication in this problem that the goal of the predictor is accuracy, it's not competing for the money.  Consistently choosing B only makes its job easier and nets you $1M per round.  The closer it is to infallible, the better for you.  Am I missing something?

@CristobolPolychronopolis - If most players just choose one-boxing, then that does make it easier for the predictor: simply adopt a probabilistic strategy, without even inspecting the player in the current game. When playing against multiple players, the pred. can also modify that strategy as they go along. The only required assumption then is that most (or just a particular % of) people will select this strategy or that strategy. Based on the empirical evidence, about 22% of philosophers don't know what to do, about 39% two-box, and 31% one-box. But that means about 50% two-box ... Ay :/

@causative: The two boxers also contend that they are yielding the maximum reward - more specifically, they contend that the one boxers are willfully leaving $1000 (the amount in the lesser box) on the table after the contents of both boxes have already been determined, which means it cannot possibly be the maximum reward. Talk of "policy optimization" sounds profound, but both sides can argue that they are producing the maximum reward, so it does not help us to distinguish which side is correct.

@Kevin The significance of the word "policy" is that it is not a decision made in the moment, it's a plan prepared beforehand. In reinforcement learning, to learn a "policy" is to learn the fixed parameters of a neural network that will later make the specific decisions. Which policy parameters yield maximum payoff? There's only one right answer. Agents with policy parameters telling them to one-box get larger reward than agents with policy parameters telling them to two-box.

@Kevin Because, when deciding what to put in the boxes, the predictor knows what the agent's policy parameters are and uses them to decide whether to give $1 million or not. So because of this, the one-box policy influences the predictor to give $1 million, long before the agent's actual choice of box occurs.

@causative: That is one model. The other model is that, as the problem is literally worded, the predictor's choice is beyond the control of the agent. In this interpretation, the agent should treat the predictor's choice as an immutable fact of nature and take both boxes.

@Kevin The predictor's choice depends on whether you're a "one-boxer" or a "two-boxer." Arguably we do have at least some ability to choose, right now as we are discussing it, whether we are a "one-boxer" or "two-boxer"; i.e. that our decision, now, of what it is best to do, would constrain or influence what we would actually do if we were in the situation. And that means we have some ability to choose, right now, whether the predictor would put the $1 million in the box.

"It is often assumed in non-cooperative game theory that if a player has a dominant strategy then it is rational to adopt it. Though arguably this fails in prisoner's dilemma situations." <<< That's not an assumption, it's a fact. But which strategy is dominant depends on the exact rules of the game. In the prisoner's dilemma, both player's choices are independent. If you can make an enforceable agreement, then it's a different game. "The prisoner's dilemma with enforceable agreement" is not the prisoner's dilemma, and has different dominant strategy than the prisoner's dilemma.

In the case of the Newcomb problem, the predictor's strategy is not independent from the agent's strategy. In fact a simple way to model the problem is to say that the agent chooses which box to take, then the predictor puts the money in the boxes accordingly. In which case it's completely clear that the dominant strategy is picking box B and getting 1000000. Wikipedia calls strategy A+B "dominant", which it would be if the predictor's strategy was independent from the agent's, but it's not. They're just confusing two different games in their analysis.

Note that it's unclear to me what you mean by "prisoner's dilemma situations". I'm guessing maybe it means "situations that are reminiscent of the prisoner's dilemma, although not necessarily exactly identical to the prisoner's dilemma." Of course, if you're in such a situation and model it as the prisoner's dilemma, and base your decisions on that model, but that model doesn't reflect the true rules of the game, then the result might be very suboptimal.

@Stef: The dominant strategy could also be to first decide you're going to only take box B, and then change your mind after the predictor has made their prediction.  The problem is whether that qualifies as a "strategy" at all (and also how the predictor can/should respond to it, which is underspecified in the problem as written).

There is a very simple way to ensure that the predictor is wrong and that you win big: In advance tell the predictor you will one-box. The predictor believes this and predicts it. You then actually two-box. -- This highlights that we make predictions all the time; trust is important; cheating wins in single games (but not in repeated games with memory where people can change their strategies).

The game-theoretic dominant strategy is only valid, as @Stef pointed out, when the options are independent from each other. When there is a dependency, the game is a different game. CDT ignores the dependency completely - in which case, two-boxing is indeed the dominant strategy.  But since that information is totally ignored CDT cannot be valid here.

@mudskipper Telling the predictor what you intend to do is irrelevant. The hypothesis behind the puzzle is that the predictor can correctly guess what you will do with high reliability. So if you lie, the predictor will most likely know. If you wish to analyse the problem as a game then there are different ways to do it. You might equally say that the player provides information to the predictor, then the predictor decides what to put into the closed box, then the player chooses which boxes to open. It is not as simple as Stef says.

@Bumble - To be more clear: my comment was intended to completely change the setup. So that assumption about reliability/infallibility/fallibility would no longer be a given. Stef's comment about dependence/independence is the crux here -- I don't actually completely understand what he meant with the rest of his comment.

In addition to Bumble's answer, I'd posit the following two reasons for confusion:

As explained on the Wikipedia page, it makes a difference whether the "reliable predictor" is 100% totally infallible and incapable of making an error, or whether it is only correct in the overwhelming majority of cases. Especially the first case opens the door to circular causation (where the future decision of the player influences the past prediction, and vice versa).
The second is that the two camps both make "local" sense: chosing A+B always nets the 1000 from A (on top what B gives) and thus the expected value is always 1000 "more" (with the problem obviously being that this is only in relative terms). Choosing B always nets 1000 less (relatively), although of course "0+1000" is smaller than "1000000-1000". This kind of confusion happens all the time (for example marginal values when looking at stepped tax systems), and while it may seem trivial to you and me, it obviously is not to other people.

As to why our brain suffers from these issues, there is simply no reasonable evolutionary pressure for our brains to develop in a way that would make them go straight like an arrow to a commonly accepted "trivial" answer. These problems do not come up in everyday life.
The conundrum of course also has been formulated with this effect in mind - it is supposed to be confusing, same like many other problems of game theory (i.e., Prisoner Dilemma, Trolley Problem, Monty Hall etc.). It is designed to show limitations of our brain's intuitive solutions for very complicated, non-every-day problems. And it gives us fodder to sharpen our minds in the art of discussing and dissecting these (at least intuitively) almost unsolvable problems.

@AnoE - "These problems do not come up in everyday life." That is something I've also been thinking about - it's surely relevant. The problem(s) seem contrived, highly unrealistic. Parfit's Hitchhiker (which is a variant) for instance can even be perceived as distasteful since it starts out with two people who are totally selfish - is that really how normal people would behave in a situation as described? But I would ask: "The problem as presented may be contrived, but can the formal problem (underneath it) perhaps model real-life situations? Can we find a non-contrived variant?"

@mudskipper, sure, Game Theory in itself is very valuable and can help with many practical decisions. Considering these paradoxa is like a weight lifter training in the gym - in itself totally useless, but when you have to move house next time, you will be happy that you have all those muscles!

@AnoE - I like that metaphor! :)

I think variants of prisoner dilemma occur in everyday life. Like for example if you have a job where you have to contact clients, when you talk to a client, but you don't know what the (other) manager has told the client before.

I would say that the reason Newcomb's problem seems to confuse a lot of people is caused by the fact that it introduces, or at the very least heavily implies, two irreconcilable premises.
Premise (1) is: "There is a reliable predictor [...]."
Note that I assume reliable here means infallible, with absolute certainty. (In contrast to, for example, "60% of the time, it works every time". For some less structured thoughts on an imperfect predictor, see below.)
Premise (2) is: "The player is given a choice [...]."
If we take premise (1) at face value, then premise (2) can not be true. If the predictor always correctly predicts the future "decision", then there can be no more choice. There is not even an actual game to be played. The payout matrix, with its four different values, is pointless and there can only ever be one outcome. All that is left for the player to do then is to confirm to the predictor the inevitable "choice", the outcome of which was never in question.
Starting off with premise (1), the scenario feels quite unintuitive, given that it fundamentally changes the way we would normally view time and causality. This counterfactual setup is probably the reason it appears wrong to some observers, who instead focus on what they know: there is a (presumably rational) choice to be made.
To conclude, the player can either believe that the predictor is perfectly reliable OR that there is a choice to be made, but not both.
The confusion results from the fact that different people take different approaches when trying to reconcile these two, fundamentally irreconcilable, premises. When one's inclinations and biases lend themselves to either overlooking one of the two rival premises, or to give one precedence over the other, that will shape the view of the proper model and the optimal strategy here. But none will be able to properly represent the Paradox.
Addendum: Imperfect predictor without knowledge of the future
Now, what would happen in the case of an imperfect predictor? Now, the questions seems even less clearly defined. What does it mean to be able to predict the future with 99% precision? Does this mean one can correctly predict a single coin toss with 0.99 probability? Then what about a series of n different coin tosses - is it still 0.99, or is that now (0.99)^n? Those options exclude each other. Does it work to predict anything, or does the prediction strictly work for the player's final choice of B or A+B, regardless of what happens after making the prediction & setting box B but before making the choice?
Or even: Can I predict my own choice with the same model the imperfect predictor uses and then, if the prediction comes up as only B, pick both for a very good shot at a sweet $1,001,000 prize? Can I deliberately go against the prediction, or will the model predict this? But since I used the same model for my prediction, I will also have predicted it, which in turn the predictor's model would have predicted, etc.. and we will end up in an endless recursive loop?
I can not see much value in investigating this further at the moment, though maybe someone can change my mind on that.

Thanks for also giving an answer to this one! :) There is an excellent book about the NP: Arif Ahmed, "Evidence, Decision and Causality" (2014). (I still haven't worked thru it completely, but it gives the most indepth arguments + counter-arguments). I recently also found a terribly amusing take down of both the evidentialist and causalists arguments by Adam Elga (who made the SBP popular): https://www.princeton.edu/~adame/papers/newcomb-university/newcomb-university.pdf

Your statement "If the predictor correctly predicted the future "decision", then there can be no more choice." is not true imo. In real life there are many occassions when we're able to correctly predict someone choices, this by itself doesn't rob them of their options. Take simple game playing for instance -- strong chess or go players win from weaker ones because they are able to predict the other's moves better.

Or consider driving on the left (or right) side of the road. We predict that most people will do so, and we better be right most of the time, else there will be accidents. We actually are right about almost always. This doesn't imply we don't have the option to drive on the other side.

But you're right that this is a "sore" point. In game theory a separate axiom (or principle) is necessary to allow predictions (infallible or fallable doesn't matter). Nigel Howard calls this the "existentialist axiom": "If certain factors affect a person's choice behavior, and he is conscious of this, he may always choose to make his behavior obey any function from the set of possible values of those factors to the set of his alternative choices." This implies that a conscious decision maker can always choose to 'disobey' any theory predicting his behavior.

Reference:  Nigel Howard, "Paradoxes of Rationality: Theory of Metagames and Political Behavior".

you are right, that sentence does not adaquately express what i wanted to say. will edit for clarity.

@mudskipper Hi and sorry for the late reply! I stand by the statement that there can be no more choice. The key word in the sentence is correctly. If you can say that with certainty before the choice is made, then there is no choice to be made. This is true, irrespective of anybody being able to predict lots of (non-deterministic) stuff with high probability. They will, however, only know for certain after the fact. If one were to pick the not predicted option, the prediction would not have been correct, which contradicts the setup. Hence no choice. (Btw, did you read my take on Groisman?)

There is nowhere any assumption in this problem (or the reasonings about it) before actual choices are known that any prediction is correct. Also, the problem is still disputed for predictors that are not 100% correct. Assuming a predictor who either in general or in regards to a particular player is only 70% correct (=believed to have a chance of 70% of being correct by the player), the problem is still disputed. If a player believes that the opponent can predict his move with p chance of being correct, this does most definitely not rob the player of his options. I don't think you'

... I don't think you've ever played competitive chess or go, playing a handicap game against a pro or a strong other amateur. If you had, you would not make the claims you are making. The fact that the other sees what you're planning to do, and can predict your moves (even before you  may be fully aware them!) does not mean you have no options...

And a perfect predictor is just the limiting case of a fallible predictor, so what you're claiming makes no sense to me. Just like a totally lousy predictor or a totally random predictor has no bearing upon the choices/options that the player has. Also - if you believe there is some problem with that, then the NC problem can just be reformulated to explicitly assume that the player in anycase is free to select any of the options. This is also the basic assumption of any game-theoretic analysis: The two players make their choices independently from each other.

@mudskipper "There is nowhere any assumption [..] that any prediction is correct" Then how do you interpret "There is a reliable predictor [...]", especially when i say that, as a premise, i assume it to be true and i take it to mean infallible..? I dont quite see what you are aiming for with the chess example. A reliable predictor, as described, could predict every move of a complete chess game in advance and none of the players could deviate from that. Neither of them has a choice. This contradiction is the core of my whole answer, together with its reversal (choice exists -> no predictor).

Sorry - to be more clear: there is no assumption that any particular prediction is known to be correct before the actual choice is observed. Neither the predictor, nor the player who believes that the predictor is p% of the time correct, will know whether the particular prediction that he is playing against is correct or not before the player's choice is made and both the prediction and the choice are observed.

@mudskipper no problem. i would argue that the phrase "there is a reliable predictor" implies (at least when assuming infallibility, as i have done) the very fact that any prediction made by that predictor has to be seen as correct, even before the choice is observed. If you take this as a given, you arrive at no choice. And if you take an actual choice as a given, you arrive at no reliable predictor. We, as well as the player in the NCP, are given these two pieces of contradictory setup, leading to the paradox.

By the same token, any hypothetical reasoning would be impossible/invalid.

Most definitely not - only if the hypothetical were to contain two or more irreconcialble premises, which may or may not be readily identifiable as such, would it suffer from the same problem as the NCP. There are lots and lots of hypotheticals that do not suffer from this problem and are perfectly possible and / or valid ( - although there may be other issues).
The issue here is that the NCP assumes both reliable prediction and choice at the same time from different agents.

Please believe whatever you want to believe. The point you bring up I can only see as obviously false. I don't see value in trying to convince you of this.

One important driver of controversy in Newcomb's Problem is the concept of causation.  Intuitively, causation has many features.  It's perfectly objective, not a matter of perspective.  It's an antisymmetric relation.  An effect never precedes its cause.  Causation is tied to fundamental physical laws.  Causation underlies effective means-ends relationships.  All these features apply in the routine encounters with causality that we deal with, so it is no wonder that we roll them all into a package deal.  Newcomb challenges us because the paradox threatens to tear the package apart.
Unfortunately, nothing in the real world meets all our intuitive desiderata for causation.  I'll confine myself to two accounts of causation that bring out important issues.  The Bayes nets discussed by Wolpert and Benford are appropriate for assessing means-ends relationships.  But their directed acyclic graphs, like the interventionist approach of Pearl, depend on dividing system from environment, endogenous from exogenous variables.

The scientist carves a piece from the universe and proclaims that
piece in ... The rest of the universe is then considered out ... This
choice of ins and outs creates asymmetry in the way we look at things
and it is this asymmetry that permits us to talk about ‘outside
intervention’ and hence about causality and cause-effect
directionality(Pearl 2nd ed.: 420).

On the other hand, the laws of physics are arguably perspective-independent.  In Causation and its Basis in Fundamental Physics, Douglas N. Kutach proposes a definition of causation in terms of fundamental laws:  see this excellent review for a summary.  Since Einstein's equations and Schrödinger's equation specify the time-evolution of events equally well backward or forward in time, Kutach's definition suggests that present events routinely causally contribute to past events as well as future ones.  But Kutach provides a partial explanation, appealing to entropy, of why we (generally) can't strategically influence the past.  The past effects (when characterized in past-centric terms) of a present action are unpredictable.  See Albert and Loewer for related arguments about entropy and the time-asymmetry of strategic influence.
Newcomb's Problem pits the "causation can't go back in time" principle against the "causation is tied to fundamental physical laws" principle.  But I would argue (if I had more space) that it is the tie to physical laws, not the direction in time, that provides the means-ends leverage.  The fact that an effect is later than our action is only required in order to know what we are doing (under the assumption that we care about the effect as it would be described contemporarily, rather than e.g. "what you get by evolving the Schrödinger equation backward from ...").
Arif Ahmed has a thought experiment called Betting On The Past which brings out the conflict even more strongly:

In my pocket (says Bob) I have a slip of paper on which is written a
proposition P. You must choose between two bets. Bet 1 is a bet on P
at 10:1 for a stake of one dollar. Bet 2 is a bet on P at 1:10 for a
stake of ten dollars. So your pay-offs are as in [Figure 1]. Before
you choose whether to take Bet 1 or Bet 2 I should tell you what P is.
It is the proposition that the past state of the world was such as to
cause you now to take Bet 2. (p. 120)

Betting On The Past bypasses the knowledge problem by specifying the desired past state in relational terms:  via your present selection, and the laws of physics.  Newcomb's Problem does a similar thing, only implicitly, and in Nozick's version, not necessarily in such a perfectly correlated manner, since all we know is that the Predictor has a long record of successes.  Nevertheless, we can use objective relationships (the laws of physics) to increase the probability of a favorable prediction, by casting aside the overgeneralization that nothing we do contributes (in one very useful sense of "contributes":  Kutach's) to the past.  It should go without saying that nothing depends on using the word "causality" for Kutach's concept, and I would actually recommend against it.  The point, rather, is to tease apart the package deal of "causality", and apply each element carefully, and if need be, separately.

Thanks! This is very insightful! I believe this clarifies one major point of contention/confusion in the reasoning about (and in) the Newcomb game: entanglement of the prediction - plus the knowledge about the past prediction - causality and choice. I didn't know about the BettingOnThePast game; pointing out the partially similarity with Newcomb is brilliant. - Ok, now I just have to read Arif Ahmed's book. Your reply has just made me positively determined to do so :)

This also directly implies that it doesn't (shouldn't) really matter if we assume the predictor is fallible or infallible. (In fact, if you agree with that -- which I do -- then you could guess that the assumption of fallibility subtly misguides people in their attempt to analyze the problem.)

Very nice combination of Newcomb and Doctor Who's Don't Blink. I really liked the smug AI of your extinct filasofs. I assume you would or could predict that I would enjoy it, if I would be curious enough to keep browsing and stumble across your story.


Why is the Newcomb problem confusing?

It isn't confusing. It asserts a contradiction: that future information can reach the past. But it can't. The reason involves 4-dimensional geometry.
But if you pretend it can, then your make-believe world is inconsistent.
It's like asserting that 2+2=5. If you do that, you can prove that any number equals any other number. Arithmetic becomes inconsistent and uninteresting.
Harry Potter books are great. I read them all. But they don't pose philosophical problems.

Some academic philosophers have claimed this too. But in this case, why do you think the other side doesn't see the point you make? Why does it remain so controversial if it would really be that simple?

The paradox does not require that the predictor is infallible. A predictor who is, say, 99% reliable and derives their predictions from a scientific study of the subject would still result in a conflict between the evidential and causal approaches to decision theory. Problems of this kind are not entirely theoretical: they can arise when information is available that is evidence for a behavioural disposition.

@Bumble Miss_Understands's counterstatement doesn't rely on the predictor being infallible either.

@RosieF Yes it does. There is nothing contradictory about being able to make highly reliable predictions about what choice a person will make in some specific situation. In fact, it is not uncommon. What might contradict our best understanding of the universe is the ability to make absolutely infallible predictions, since this would in effect be a form of backward causation.

@Bumble Perhaps, but that's not relevant here. A premise of the paradox is that the player believes the "predictor" almost (albeit not 100%) reliably predicts their choice. Even if not 100% reliable, the predictor would rely on future information reaching the past, as Miss_Understands put it. A slightly noisy signal has information. That so unrealistic a premise implies an absurdity is no paradox. In real life, the player needn't believe any claim about any purported "predictor". They needn't even believe that there's any $1,000,000 at all available to be put into box B.

@RosieF We make highly reliable predictions all the time. This does not give rise to a paradox. I predict that if someone today offered you a gift of $1000 with no strings attached you would take it. That prediction will work extremely reliably across a very wide range of people. All that Newcomb requires is that there is some combination of scientific tests that will allow a highly reliable prediction of whether a person will choose one or two boxes. There is nothing absurd about that assumption and it does not conflict with any laws of nature.

@Bumble Could you elaborate why the predictor does not need to be infallible? And how that is more than your opinion? Because you could very well argue that "reliable" requires certainty. That only if something is certain you reliably deduce information from it. Sure that is an opinion in itself, but if reliable just means highly lightly you'd also need the degree of accuracy to actually rely on it, wouldn't you?

@haxor789 Suppose the predictor is 99% reliable, i.e. 1% error rate both positive and negative. Then the expected return from 1-boxing is $990,000 and from 2-boxing is $11,000. So evidential decision theory says 1-box. But causal decision theory dictates that we screen off events that are causally independent of my actions. My actions cannot change the contents of the closed box: it is a fixed and immutable but unknown X. So the choice is between having X or having X + $1000, and whatever X is, having an extra $1000 is always better.

@haxor789 So the paradox of having conflicting criteria of rational decisions remains. This is not something I invented. There is a considerable published literature on Newcomb's paradox and this is a fairly common observation. Nozick's original paper on the subject even speaks of the prediction being "almost certain".

@Bumble So the slightly imperfect predictor "keeps it real" while keeping both options alive? I'd still stand by my initial first sentence though that the problem is that you have no idea of how any of that works. Like you don't know the odds, so it's moot to compute them as they are based in guesses and faith, you don't know what motivates the predictor so you can only guess, you don't know if your actions impact the predictor prior to the prediction or if you ever had a chance to make an impression in the first place... So whether "rationality" even is a factor relies on your agency ...

@Bumble ... and you can't be sure that you have any. Well outside of being a 2-boxer in which case it's your decision to see both options. Though very likely you end up with a subpar outcome because of that. It's even possible that this is just statistics and that because you tried to cheat on the predictor, the predictor will adapt the algorithm and you'll remain a one off, though what makes one think one is the first to do if near 50% think of that. Though maybe one actually is the first contender at all. None of that is known everything is speculation, including whether rationality matters.

@haxor789 I may well know how reliable the predictor is. It may have performed the same experiment on thousands of other people with a 99% success rate and I have no reason to think I am special or that I can cheat it. If the predictor was just guessing with a 50:50 outcome of being right then the expectation value calculation would favour two-boxing. But the point of the puzzle that is if we grant that the predictor is highly reliable then I have conflicting criteria of how to make a rational decision.

@Bumble 2 problems a) how can we be sure that the content of the box and our actions are causally independent and that our action or precursors thereof didn't give away the game? b) I'd certainly be thinking, and probably even am, special if I anticipated to have solo B be nothing or A+B to be $1,001,000 because either way I'd be an outlier to the rule, so in consequence I would have fooled the predictor and I would not know how or why.

@haxor789 The way the puzzle is formulated, the closed box has been either filled or not. It cannot be changed. This is the point behind imagining an observer who can see into the box. Whatever prediction the predictor made, there is no going back now. So the contents of the closed box are causally independent of my decision. Since there is no backwards causation, there is nothing I can do now that will cause the closed box to change its contents. But there is also no reason to suppose I can cheat the predictor. Whatever my chain of thought, the predictor has mostly likely anticipated it.

@Bumble The question as to whether your choice has an influence on the prediction kinda rests upon the question "what is your choice" and I'm not talking about A+B/B, but about whether that is just the act of picking or the entire decision making process. If that is a split second decision than they are causally independent, if that is a process followed a set path even before the prediction and continues on that path until you actually pick something then your decision did in fact cause the prediction. Also if you think "changing your choice" is possible, you assume you can fool the predictor

@haxor789 Facts about my state in the past may be described as playing a part in causing the prediction. And maybe if determinism is true those facts lead inexorably to the decision that I make. But I don't know what decision I am going to make without actually making it, so that doesn't help me. Causal decision theory dictates I should do whatever causes the best results. And since I can't cause the past, I should hold the present state of affairs as a constant. If this gives the wrong result, we want to understand why. There are several possible responses in the published literature.

The one-boxer position is intuitively straightforward and has been explained in other answers in some depth (but in short: the one boxer asserts that the outcome in which you choose both boxes, but box B still contains $1M is either impossible or improbable enough that one-boxing is a superior overall strategy). So this answer will specifically focus on the two-boxer position, which I think is the more confusing one.
Let's imagine a simpler version of the problem, where the only information we are given is the following:

Box A definitely contains $1000.
Box B might contain $1 million, or it might not.
The contents of box B have been determined (by some unknown-to-us process) and cannot change now.

We are then asked to choose between both boxes and only B. The obvious answer is to take both boxes, because the process by which B's contents are determined is irrelevant - either it contains $1 million or not, but no matter what is in B, we get an extra $1000 if we take both.
The operator of the game then reveals to us that box B's contents were in fact determined by the predictor as in the original problem, and asks if we wish to change to only taking box B, or stick with our original choice of both boxes. The one boxer position is that we ought to change. But a paragraph ago, we concluded that any information about the contents of B is irrelevant, so it should not affect our choice of boxes. Either the previous paragraph contains a logical error, or the one boxer position is in error. Since there is no obvious error in the previous paragraph, the two boxer position is that the one boxer position must be in error, and so we should stick with two boxes.
The difficulty is that there is also no obvious error in the one boxer position, which is why Newcomb's problem is confusing.
I should also note that several answers have claimed the problem is a "fantasy" or otherwise impossible, but as the original formulation explicitly notes, the predictor need not be infallible, just moderately better than chance. Humans are more predictable than a fair coin, and so such a predictor is obviously possible. An infallible predictor does not materially change the problem, it merely casts it in a starker light... unless you go to the point of claiming that an outcome where the predictor is wrong is somehow physically impossible, in the sense that it is physically prevented from happening by any means, which does indeed take you well beyond the realm of normal physics and into the world of fantasy. But the one boxer position merely requires a straightforward application of expected value to the fallible predictor, and so I refuse to further address a physically infallible predictor as it is beyond the scope of the original problem as stated by Newcomb (and also, in my opinion, not very interesting since it is unphysical, whereas the original problem is something you could actually do in real life).

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
